# How can I add an Average column to this text table?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm building my first dashboard in Tableau and I'm just beginning to learn all the nuances. Right now, I have a basic text table as shown in the image below. I'm trying to add an "Average" column at then end which will give the average per "Assignee" across the 5 fiscal week's shown. I assume there must be a pretty simple way to do this, but I've searched all over and cannot figure it out. I've been able to change the "Grand Total" column to show averages, but not add an additional column so I can display both data points. Can anyone provide some insight into how to make this work?

[image: Tableau]

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you can do:

1. Go To "Analysis/ Total/ Show Row Grand Totals" and the go to "Analysis/ Total/ Total All Using/ Average" This will give you the row and column averages. Your questions sounds like you want row average but column total, so you should try the second option.
2. Create a calculated field with `WINDOW_AVG(sum([YourMeasure]))` (Replace [YourMeasure] with the meassure you want to average. I couldn't see the full name in the screenshot) I will call it `AverageMeasure`
   Then drag the `AverageMeasure` pill into the rows shelf, right click it and  choose "Discrete".
   It should look something like this now (I used the Tableau default data set):
   [image]

If you want to format the number properly, right click on the `AverageMeasure` in the measures section, choose Default Properties/ Number Format and choose whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Alexander! Unfortunately, I don't believe either of those will work. What I'm looking for is having column totals, but both total and average for the rows. See [this mockup](http://imgur.com/p8RZV3u) I created with the averages added at the end. When I try the 2nd solution you provided, if I change the AverageMeasure to "discrete", I get an error saying "Cannot turn on Grand Totals for discrete measures". Any more ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue and cannot average the GrandTotal Column :(